# $this->auth->login() Not Working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hello Everyone i'm trying to login after i have successfully add user data into database, but login is not working,I'm new to cakephp.Please Help me out.
here is the code

appcontroller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
   'DebugKit.Toolbar' ,'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);}
```

UsersController:

```
public function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('Post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }//$this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

login.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('login');
```

?>

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I have dubug $this->Auth->login() , it returns false.

Comment: Should i change the cakephp version or somthing else ? Any Help please

Comment: Your Auth component configuration should have a key 'authenticate' for example with ['Form']

Comment: I have used both 'Form ' and 'Basic'. But still no luck ?

Comment: DiDos .. can you give a sample code ? please

Comment: @MuhammadUsman can you also share the user creation part? I guess you simply have the "wrong password" - for example troubles with the hashing.

Comment: i'm not using any hashing algo for now.
User:

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel
{

}

Comment: look at your users table password field, how save it.

Comment: @salines .. i did not understand what you are talking about.
can you please elaborate ?
getting frustrated.

Comment: There is a possibility that the password field is short. For example, your field is set to max 5 characters, and you enter a password with more than 5 characters. This often occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Add password hashing to your User model

User.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model'); 

class User extends AppModel {
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {    
        if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }

    }
 }
```

after that truncate your user table and save fresh user and then check again the login.